Calculation of IOU for instance segmentation (mask rcnn from detectron2)
I have do research online
For the calculation of IOU is with equation below
IOU EQUATION

How to get the ground truth mask and instance prediction mask from the model training?
How to calculate the IOU for instance predictions

For my code, i have use mask rcnn do a transfer learning. Below is the code for instance predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
predicted_images_path = os.path.abspath("/content/predicted_label")
dataset_dicts_validation = DatasetCatalog.get("void-detection-3-valid")
for d in dataset_dicts_validation:
  im = cv2.imread(d["file_name"])
  outputs = predictor(I'm)
  v = Visualizer(im[:, :, ::-1],
               metadata = metadata,
               scale=0.5,
               instance_mode=ColorMode.IMAGE_BW)

out_1 = v.draw_instance_predictions(outputs["instances"].to("cpu"))
fig = plt.figure(frameon=False, dpi=1)
fig.set_size_inches(1024,1024)
ax = plt.Axes(fig, [0., 0., 1., 1.])
ax.set_axis_off()
fig.add_axes(ax)
ax.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(out.get_image()[:, :, ::-1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), aspect='auto')
fig.savefig(f"{predicted_images_path}/{d['file_name'].split('/')[-1]}")

The result come out is show at image below
Instance prediction result
For my labeling, i use ROBOFLOW to do labeling,
